# Encoding Issue while Export from JabRef to .CSV

Tags: bibtex, unicode, jabref, excel, listingsutf8

I am trying to export bib to .csv and there are many issues being faced but most important is encoding:

1. special symbols are not converted  properly to the same symbols e.g. " " changing to different symbols
2. If my Jabref entry has (http://www.​uppaal.​org/​) content then it is converted to ([http://â](http://%C3%A2)€‹www.â€‹uppaal.â€‹org/â€‹).
3. Author in other languages​ correct in Jabref António José Silva and Jorge Gustavo Rocha and in .csv it is like 
   {AntÃ³nio JosÃ© Silva and Jorge Gustavo Rocha}

The encoding of JabRef is UTF-8

Please help to resolve the issue and also tell if this problem with Excel Encoding

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using JabRef 3.3, exportation to CSV looks fine with an editor supporting UTF-8.
The issue is the importation of an UTF-8 CSV file into excel. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002256/is-it-possible-to-force-excel-recognize-utf-8-csv-files-automatically